# How can i control the number of pages to be print using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to control the pages that is to be print by following options: 
1. Print All Pages
2. Print Current Page
3. Print selected pages (like 3,4,6-9 etc)

By using window.print() all the pages gets selected by default. How can i pass the required pages for printing, so that window.print() have those pages only. I need to use JavaScript for this purpose.

Comment: You can try to defines some rules using css @page rule https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/@page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi I made an some code sample based on my comment https://jsfiddle.net/hg9cn7hs/

in this example div with class `second-page` will be ignored in print, you need to add just the custom logic for your scenario.